# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377, Ubuntu 17.04, ethernet and wifi connection not working

Tags: command-line, networking, drivers, atheros

I have Dell inspiron 15 5000 with windows and Ubuntu on dualboot and as I wrote in the title, the problem is the internet connection that is not working with ethernet cable and wifi, only on Ubuntu. Searcing on internet I found this repository [https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware](http://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware), but I can't understand what I should do or whitch command i need to write on Linux terminal. And also if is the correct way to resolve the probelm.

I can use the wifi connection to entry on router option, but i can surf on internet.

`grep -i dns /var/log/syslog`:

```
Jul 10 00:17:53 yarrai-Inspiron-5567 systemd-resolved[1099]: DNSSEC validation failed for question ntp.ubuntu.com IN SOA: failed-auxiliary 
Jul 10 00:17:53 yarrai-Inspiron-5567 systemd-resolved[1099]: DNSSEC validation failed for question ntp.ubuntu.com IN A: failed-auxiliary 
Jul 10 00:17:54 yarrai-Inspiron-5567 systemd-resolved[1099]: DNSSEC
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i dns` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: the row's result are  a very big quantity of string like thise:
Jul 10 00:17:53 yarrai-Inspiron-5567 systemd-resolved[1099]: DNSSEC validation failed for question ntp.ubuntu.com IN SOA: failed-auxiliary
Jul 10 00:17:53 yarrai-Inspiron-5567 systemd-resolved[1099]: DNSSEC validation failed for question ntp.ubuntu.com IN A: failed-auxiliary
Jul 10 00:17:54 yarrai-Inspiron-5567 systemd-resolved[1099]: DNSSEC 

but after that internet is working

Comment: Ahhh! DNSSEC! You might try this first: https://superuser.com/questions/1153203/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-resolved-dns-lookups-randomly-fail/1200745#1200745

Comment: thank you very much!! after some check and some restart is still working!!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.

Comment: Answered with a link to https://superuser.com/questions/1153203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to OP’s comment the following answer resolved the issue:

> Ubuntu 17.04 can not resolve DNS servers with DNSSEC support as of 2017-04-18.  Disable DNSSEC with this daemon:
>
> ```sh
> sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d
> printf "[Resolve]\nDNSSEC=no\n" | sudo tee /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/no-dnssec.conf
> ```
>
> Reconfigure resolvconf if needed:
>
> ```sh
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
> ```
>
> Say yes to "prepare /etc/resolve.conf for dynamic updates?" And reboot.

<sup>([source](//superuser.com/a/1200745/238583))</sup>